# VBA - Dictionary not showing all values with large number of rows

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

The number of rows in the excel file is 123568 and unique values are 563.

However when I run the below code I get only 199 unique values. For a small number of rows 15 to 20 the below code gives unique values accurately.

```
Sub Main_Compare()

Set wb = thisWorkbook
Set hWs = wb.Sheets("zz")

Set rgBase = hWs.Range("A1").currentregion

    Dim dictBase As New Dictionary
    Set dictBase = ReadList(rgBase.Value)
    
    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In dictBase
        Debug.Print key, dictBase(key)
    Next key

End Sub

Public Function ReadList(arr As Variant) As Dictionary

    Dim dict As New Dictionary
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        dict(arr(i, 1)) = 0
    Next i
    
    Set ReadList = dict
End Function
```

Comment: Your code works for me.  Since you are using `CurrentRegion`, are you sure there are no gaps in your data?  Add `Debug.Print rgBase.Address` just after `Set rgBase = ...` to verify the range

Comment: Debug.Print/Immediate pane only display the last 200 or so rows of text if that's how you're measuring it....  Try `MsgBox dictBase.Count` instead